# Rewrite Rules, Query Vars and Pagination

Tags: rewrite-rules, paged

Putt a lot of research in and did a lot of testing for this issue and I don't think I am going to solve this by myself at this point.

What we have:

A page with a permalink with one shortcode.
That shortcode is resolved via plugin, which provides different views / outputs relatively by the url-path:

/dashboard/admin <-- the WP page permalink

/dashboard/admin/*trainers/list* <-- path without own permalink

This all works fine with this rule:

```
dashboard/admin/(.*)
```

**Now to the issue:**

/dashboard/admin/***trainers/list/page/2***

This url doesn't trigger the pagination to go to page 2, the paged var is empty (null).

The rule:

```
dashboard/trainers/(.+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$
```

This rule matches perfectly with preg_match testers and the test plugin "Rewrite Rules Inspector":

[image]

The add_rewrite_rule part:

```
    $rule = $path.'/(.+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$';
    add_rewrite_rule( $rule, 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&dashview=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]','top');
    $this->flush($rule);
    $rule = $path.'/(.*)';
    add_rewrite_rule( $rule, 'index.php?pagename='.$path.'&dashview=$matches[1]','top');
    $this->flush($rule);
```

*( $path is just "dashboard/admin" )*

**My rule for paged pages gets overridden by the second rule. How can I prevent that?**

Debug I did:

*Using a redirect_canonical filter callback, and returning the requested URL with "?paged=2" works, and will get me to page 2 of the list.*

Comment: Your rewrite rule only has two capture groups, there is no `$matches[3]`

Comment: WP doesn't match the whole string as first match. I see, thank you very much. Problem solved.